# Entity Framework in stock market

Tags: entity

```
public List<StockMarket> ReadAllRecords(string TxtFilePath, string TxtFileName)
{
    List<StockMarket> Stock = new List<StockMarket>();
    String[] a = File.ReadAllLines(TxtFilePath + TxtFileName);

    foreach (var b in a)
    {
        String[] d = b.Split(',');
        StockMarket S = new StockMarket();
        S.ProductId = d[0];
        S.ProductName = d[1];
        S.StockId = d[2];
        S.StockName = d[3];
        S.StockPrice = d[4];
        S.NumberofStocks = d[5];
        S.Currency = d[6];
        Stock.Add(S);
    }

    return Stock;
}

public List<StockMarket> GetValidRecords(List<StockMarket> Stock, string ErrorFilePath, string ErrorFileName)
{
    List<StockMarket> Valid = new List<StockMarket>();
    List<StockMarket> InValid = new List<StockMarket>();

    foreach (var s in Stock)
    {
        bool ValidRecord = true;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.ProductId) || !s.ProductId.All(Char.IsDigit))
        {
            ValidRecord = false;
        }

        if (!s.ProductName.StartsWith("ABC") || s.ProductName.Length != 6)
        {
            ValidRecord = false;
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.StockId) || !s.StockId.All(Char.IsDigit))
        {
            ValidRecord = false;
        }

        if (!s.StockName.StartsWith("SBC") || s.StockName.Length != 7)
        {
            ValidRecord = false;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.StockPrice))
        {
            ValidRecord = false;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.NumberofStocks) || !s.NumberofStocks.All(char.IsDigit))
        {
            ValidRecord = false;
        }

        if (!(s.Currency.Equals("INR") || s.Currency.Equals("USD") || s.Currency.Equals("EUR")))
        {
            ValidRecord = false;
        }

        if (ValidRecord)
        {
            Valid.Add(s);
        }
        else
        {
            InValid.Add(s);
        }
    }

    LogErrorRecord(InValid, ErrorFilePath, ErrorFileName);
    return Valid;
}

public List<StockMarket> CalculateTotalPrice(List<StockMarket> Stock)
{
    foreach (var s in Stock)
    {
        if (s.Currency.Equals("INR"))
        {
            s.TotalPrice = (Convert.ToDouble(s.StockPrice) * Convert.ToDouble(s.NumberofStocks) * 1).ToString();
        }
        else if (s.Currency.Equals("USD"))
        {
            s.TotalPrice = (Convert.ToDouble(s.StockPrice) * Convert.ToDouble(s.NumberofStocks) * 0.5).ToString();
        }
        else if (s.Currency.Equals("EUR"))
        {
            s.TotalPrice = (Convert.ToDouble(s.StockPrice) * Convert.ToDouble(s.NumberofStocks) * 0.75).ToString();
        }
    }

    return Stock;
}

public void LogErrorRecord(List<StockMarket> InvalidStock, string ErrorFilePath, string ErrorFileName)
{
    List<String> InvalidItems = new List<string>();

    foreach (var I in InvalidStock)
    {
        InvalidItems.Add(I.ProductId + " " + I.ProductName + " " + I.StockId + " " + I.StockName + " " + I.StockPrice + " " + I.NumberofStocks + " " + I.Currency);
    }

    File.AppendAllLines(ErrorFilePath + ErrorFileName, InvalidItems);
}

public void SavetoDB(List<StockMarket> Stock, SqlConnection connection)
{
    String Query = "insert into StockMarket(ProductId,Productname,StockId,StockName,StockPrice,NumberofStocks,Currency,TotalPrice) Values(@ProductId,@ProductName,@StockId,@StockName,@StockPrice,@NumberofStocks,@Currency,@TotalPrice)";
    connection.Open();

    foreach (var a in Stock)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", a.ProductId);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", a.ProductName);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StockId", a.StockId);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StockName", a.StockName);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StockPrice", a.StockPrice);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NumberofStocks", a.NumberofStocks);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Currency", a.Currency);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalPrice", a.TotalPrice);
        int b = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    connection.Close();
}

public void SaveDistinctProductName(List<StockMarket> Stock, SqlConnection connection)
{
    String Query = "if not exists( select * from Product where ProductId = @ProductId) begin insert into Product (ProductId,ProductName) Values(@ProductId,@ProductName)end";
    connection.Open();

    foreach (var a in Stock)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", a.ProductId);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", a.ProductName);
        int b = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    connection.Close();
}

public void SaveDistinctStockName(List<StockMarket> Stock, SqlConnection connection)
{
    String Query = "if not exists( select * from Stock where StockId = @StockId) begin insert into Stock (StockId,StockName) Values(@StockId,@StockName)end";
    connection.Open();

    foreach (var a in Stock)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StockId", a.StockId);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StockName", a.StockName);
        int b = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Entity Framework allows you to create a model by writing code or using boxes and lines in the EF Designer. Both of these approaches can be used to target an existing database or create a new database. This short video explains the differences and how to find the one that is right for you.

Please let me know the overview of the code

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EmployeeValidation
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
              /*
               * Pass the file path, file names and connection string if any in this method alone. 
               * Do not hardcode in any other methods
               */
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NA03OSDVP00746\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBEmployeeValidation;Integrated Security=True");
            EmployeeValidator empValidator = new EmployeeValidator();
            empValidator.ProcessData(@"D:\Employee_Validator\Input File\", "Emp_122014.xml", @"D:\Employee_Validator\Error File\", "Emp_122014.xml", connection);

        }
    }
}

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Data.Linq;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using System.IO;

    namespace EmployeeValidation
    {
        public class EmployeeValidator
        {
            /*
            * Do not remove the attached TestProject. It is meant for auto evaluation of your source code.
            * Do not attach any test classess to the attached test project.
            * Do not attach any new test projects.
            * You are not required to write any automated test cases. You are supposed to write only the code.
            */

            public void ProcessData(string xmlFilePath, string xmlFileName,string errorFilePath, string errorFileName, SqlConnection connection)
            {
                //Do your logic here
                //Step 1           
                //ReadAllEmployeesFromXmlFile
                List<Employee> lstemp = new List<Employee>();
                List<Employee> validemp = new List<Employee>();
                lstemp = ReadAllEmployeesFromXmlFile(xmlFilePath,xmlFileName);
                validemp = PickValidEmployees(lstemp);
                SaveValidEmployeesToDB(validemp, connection);
                ReadfromDBtoTxt(connection);

                //Step 2           
                //PickValidEmployees
                //Step 3
                //SaveValidEmployeesToDataBase           

            }
            public List<Employee> ReadAllEmployeesFromXmlFile(string xmlFilePath, string xmlFileName)
            {
                //Read the employee details from the xml file and return it in List collection
                //Do not hardcode the filename and the file path here
                //Do not return the date with time appended to it.

                string employeefile = xmlFilePath + xmlFileName;
                List<Employee> empdetail = new List<Employee>();
                XElement getelementfile = XElement.Load(employeefile);
                IEnumerable<XElement> items = getelementfile.Elements();
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    string _EmployeeId = item.Element("EmployeeId").Value;
                    string _EmployeeName = item.Element("EmployeeName").Value;
                    string _EmailId = item.Element("EmailId").Value;
                    string _DateOfJoining = item.Element("DateOfJoining").Value;
                    empdetail.Add(new Employee(){ EmployeeId= _EmployeeId,
                                                  EmployeeName= _EmployeeName,
                                                  EmailId=_EmailId,
                                                  DateOfJoining=_DateOfJoining
                                                });
                }
          return empdetail;
            }

            public List<Employee> PickValidEmployees(List<Employee> employees)
            {
                //Pick the valid employees from the List collection
                //Return the valid employees in a List
                List<Employee> valid = new List<Employee>();
                List<Employee> Invalid = new List<Employee>();
                List<string> empnum = new List<string>();
                bool isvalid = true;
                foreach(Employee em in employees)
                {
                    Regex rgxisnumeric = new Regex(@"^\d$");
                    Regex rgxisalphanumeric=new Regex( @"^\d*[a-zA-Z]{1,}\d*");
                    Regex rgxemail = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
                    Regex rgxDate= new Regex(@"^((0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/((0|1)[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/((19|20)\d\d))$");
                    if (!empnum.Contains(em.EmployeeId))
                    {
                        empnum.Add(em.EmployeeId);
                        isvalid = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isvalid = false;
                    }

                    int empname;
                   isvalid= isvalid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(em.EmployeeId)) && (rgxisnumeric.IsMatch(em.EmployeeId));
                   isvalid= isvalid && (int.TryParse(em.EmployeeName, out empname)== false);
                   isvalid= isvalid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(em.EmployeeName)) && (rgxisalphanumeric.IsMatch(em.EmployeeName));
                   isvalid= isvalid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(em.EmailId)) && (rgxemail.IsMatch(em.EmailId));
                   isvalid= isvalid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(em.DateOfJoining)) && (rgxDate.IsMatch(em.DateOfJoining));
                    if(isvalid)
                    {
                        DateTime dt;
                        isvalid= isvalid && DateTime.TryParseExact(em.DateOfJoining,"MM/dd/yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
                    }
                    if(isvalid)
                    {
                        valid.Add(em);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Invalid.Add(em);
                    }

                }
                SaveInValidEmployeesTotxt(Invalid);

                return valid;//Return only valid employees in List
            }

            public void SaveValidEmployeesToDB(List<Employee> employees, SqlConnection connection)
            {
                //Do not Prefix Database name in the SQL Query. Query should be "Insert into SBA.TableName"
                //Should not be "Insert into DatabaseName.SBA.TableName"
                //Do not hardcode the connection string here

                SqlConnection conn = connection;

                foreach(Employee emp in employees)
                {
                    string command = "Insert into SBA.Employees (EmployeeId,EmployeeName,EmailId,DateOfJoining) values (@EmployeeId,@EmployeeName,@EmailId,@DateOfJoining)";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, conn);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId",emp.EmployeeId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName",emp.EmployeeName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId",emp.EmailId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfJoining",DateTime.Parse(emp.DateOfJoining).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                }
            }
            public void SaveInValidEmployeesTotxt(List<Employee> Invalid)
            {

                string invalidpath = @"D:\Employee_Validator\Error File\Emp_122014.xml";
                XmlSerializer serialise = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Employee>));
                TextWriter writeinvalid = new StreamWriter(invalidpath);
                serialise.Serialize(writeinvalid,Invalid);
           }
            public void ReadfromDBtoTxt(SqlConnection connection)
            {
                string newfilepath = @"D:\Employee_Validator\DBtoTXT\EmpoValid_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMyyyy") + ".txt";
                List<Employee> dbtotextlist = new List<Employee>();
                if (!File.Exists(newfilepath))
                {
                    var g= File.Create(newfilepath);
                    g.Close();
               }
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from SBA.Employees",connection);
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader readdata = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (readdata.Read())
                {

                    dbtotextlist.Add(new Employee
                    {
                    EmployeeId = readdata["EmployeeId"].ToString(),
                    EmployeeName = readdata["EmployeeName"].ToString(),
                    EmailId = readdata["EmailId"].ToString(),
                    DateOfJoining = readdata["DateOfJoining"].ToString()
                    });

                }
                sconnection.Close();
                StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(newfilepath);
                foreach(Employee s in dbtotextlist)
                {   
                        sw.WriteLine(s.EmployeeId+","+s.EmployeeName+","+s.EmailId+","+ DateTime.Parse(s.DateOfJoining).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
                }
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
                  }
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlConnection connectionObject = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NA03OSDVP00746\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog= DBFXCalculation;Integrated Security=True");
        Main fxcalculatorobj = new Main();
        fxcalculatorobj.ProcessData(@"D:\frameworksample\Input File\", "TradeOrders_032013.txt",
            @"D:\frameworksample\ErrorLog\", "InvalidRecords_032014.txt", connectionObject,
            @"D:\frameworksample\Archive\", "TradeOrders_032013_Processed.txt");

        /*
        * Pass the file path, file names and connection string in this method alone. 
        * Do not hardcode in any other methods
        */ 

    }




using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Reflection;

    namespace frameworksample
    {

        class Main
        {

            public void ProcessData(string sourceFolder, string fileName, string errorLogFilePath,
               string errorLogFileName, SqlConnection connectionObject,
               string archiveFilePath, string archiveFileName)
            {

                //Step 1:ReadAllDataFromInputFile
                List<Trade> trades = ReadAllDataFromInputFile(sourceFolder, fileName);

                //Step 2:PickValidTradeDetails;
                List<Trade> validateTrade = PickValidTradeDetails(trades, errorLogFilePath, errorLogFileName);

                //Step 3: SaveValidRecordsToDB            
                SaveValidRecordsToDB(validateTrade, connectionObject);

                //Step 4:CalculateFXRate             
                List<FXRate> fxRates = CalculateFXRate(connectionObject);

                //Step 5:SaveFXRate  
                //List<FXRate> fxRates = new List<FXRate>();
                SaveFXRate(fxRates, connectionObject);

                //Step 6:CopyToArchive  

                CopyToArchive(archiveFilePath, archiveFileName);

                //Validate data

            }

            public List<Trade> ReadAllDataFromInputFile(string sourceFolder, string fileName)
            {
                List<Trade> trades = new List<Trade>();

                //Do your logic to read file and storing it into list of trades ..here..
                //Do not hardcode the filename and the file path here
                using(StreamReader sr= File.OpenText(sourceFolder+fileName))
                {
                    string s="";
                    while((s=sr.ReadLine())!=null)
                    {

                           if(s.Contains(','))

                           {
                               string[] splited= s.Split(',');
                               Trade tradeitem= new Trade();
                               tradeitem.TradeId= splited[0];
                               tradeitem.ISIN= splited[1];
                               tradeitem.TradeDate= splited[2];
                               tradeitem.MaturityDate= splited[3];
                               tradeitem.SchemeName= splited[4];
                               tradeitem.TradeType= splited[5];
                               tradeitem.Currency= splited[6];
                               tradeitem.Amount= splited[7];
                               trades.Add(tradeitem);                           

                           }
                        }
                    }


                return trades;
            }
            public List<Trade> PickValidTradeDetails(List<Trade> trades, string errorLogFilePath, string errorLogFileName)
            {
                //email: \w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)* ,,,, \b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
                // Step 1 : filter the valid trades and invalid trades, save the invalid
                List<Trade> validTrades = new List<Trade>(); //identify all the valid trades and assign.
                //Do not hardcode the filename and the file path here

                List<Trade> invalidTrade = new List<Trade>();
                bool isValid = true;
                foreach (Trade x in trades)
                {
                    isValid=(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TradeId));
                    Regex rgxtradeid = new Regex(@"\bTR\d{3}\b");
                    isValid = isValid && rgxtradeid.IsMatch(x.TradeId);
                    isValid=(isValid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ISIN)));
                    Regex rgxisin = new Regex(@"\bISIN\d{3}\b");
                    isValid = (rgxisin.IsMatch(x.ISIN));
                    Regex rgxdate = new Regex("((0[1-9]|1[0-2])\\/((0|1)[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\\/((19|20)\\d\\d))$");
                    DateTime dt;
                    isValid = (isValid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TradeDate)) && (rgxdate.IsMatch(x.TradeDate)));
                    isValid = (isValid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.MaturityDate)) && (rgxdate.IsMatch(x.MaturityDate)));
                    if (isValid)
                    {
                        DateTime MD = DateTime.Parse(x.MaturityDate);
                        DateTime TD = DateTime.Parse(x.TradeDate);
                        int year = MD.Year - TD.Year;
                        isValid = isValid && (year > 5);
                        isValid = isValid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TradeType));
                        isValid = isValid && (x.Currency.Equals("GBP") || x.Currency.Equals("EUR") || x.Currency.Equals("USD") || x.Currency.Equals("INR"));
                        isValid = isValid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Amount));
                        int i;
                        bool isnumeric = int.TryParse(x.Amount, out i);
                        isValid = isValid && (isnumeric);
                    }
                    if(isValid)
                                                            {
                                                             Trade val= new Trade();
                                                                val.TradeId= x.TradeId;
                                                            val.ISIN=  x.ISIN;
                                                          val.TradeDate= x.TradeDate;
                                                          val.MaturityDate= x.MaturityDate;
                                                          val.SchemeName= x.SchemeName;
                                                          val.TradeType= x.TradeType;
                                                          val.Currency= x.Currency;
                                                          val.Amount= x.Amount;
                                                          validTrades.Add(val);
                                                            }
                    else
                    {
                                                            Trade valerror= new Trade();
                                                            valerror.TradeId= x.TradeId;
                                                            valerror.ISIN=  x.ISIN;
                                                            valerror.TradeDate= x.TradeDate;
                                                            valerror.MaturityDate= x.MaturityDate;
                                                            valerror.SchemeName= x.SchemeName;
                                                            valerror.TradeType= x.TradeType;
                                                            valerror.Currency= x.Currency;
                                                            valerror.Amount= x.Amount;
                                                            invalidTrade.Add(valerror);
                    }

                  }
                SaveInvalidRecordsToLogFile(invalidTrade, errorLogFilePath, errorLogFileName);
                // SaveInvalidRecordsToLogFile(List<Trades>); // pass all the invalid trades to log...

                return validTrades;


            }
            public bool SaveInvalidRecordsToLogFile(List<Trade> invalidTrades, string errorLogFilePath, string errorLogFileName)
            {
                //Do your logic here
                //Do not hardcode the filename and the file path here
                if (invalidTrades != null && invalidTrades.Count > 0)
                {
                    string errorLogfile = errorLogFilePath + errorLogFileName;
                    try
                    {
                        if (!File.Exists(errorLogfile))
                        {
                            var invalidfile = File.Create(errorLogfile);
                            invalidfile.Close();
                        }

                        using (StreamWriter swinvalid = File.AppendText(errorLogfile))
                        {
                            swinvalid.WriteLine("TradeId|ISIN|TradeDate|MaturityDate|Tradetype|Currency|Amount");
                            foreach (Trade ivt in invalidTrades)
                            {
                                swinvalid.WriteLine(ivt.TradeId + "," + ivt.ISIN + "," + ivt.TradeDate + "," + ivt.MaturityDate + "'" + ivt.TradeType + "," + ivt.Currency + "," + ivt.Amount);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new FXCalculatorException(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            public bool SaveValidRecordsToDB(List<Trade> validTrades, SqlConnection sqlConnectionObject)
            {
                //Do your logic here to upload to DB table
                //Do not hardcode the connection string here
                //Do not create the redundant connection Object for SqlConnection, use the conncetionObject given in the method parameter.
                //Do not Prefix Database name in the SQL Query. Query should be "Insert into SBA.TableName"
                //Should not be "Insert into DatabaseName.SBA.TableName"
                //var ConnectionString = sqlConnectionObject.ConnectionString;
                if (validTrades.Count > 0 && validTrades != null)
                {
                    SqlConnection conn = sqlConnectionObject;

                        conn.Open();
                    foreach (Trade valid in validTrades)
                    {
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(("Insert into SBA.Trade_Details (TradeID,ISIN,TradeDate,MaturityDate,SchemeName,TradeType,Currency,Amount) values (@TradeID,@ISIN,@TradeDate,@MaturityDate,@SchemeName,@TradeType,@Currency,@Amount)"),conn);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TradeID",valid.TradeId);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ISIN", valid.ISIN);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TradeDate", valid.TradeDate);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MaturityDate", valid.MaturityDate);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SchemeName", valid.SchemeName);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TradeType", valid.TradeType);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Currency", valid.Currency);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", valid.Amount);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        }
                    conn.Close();
                }



                return true;
            }
            public List<FXRate> CalculateFXRate(SqlConnection sqlConnectionObject)
            {
                // TODO :Read the Trade details for TradeType FX from database and  calculate the rates.
                //  Calculate the rate for each trade and add in a list of FXRates. 
                //Do not Prefix Database name in the SQL Query. Query should be "Insert into SBA.TableName"
                //Should not be "Insert into DatabaseName.SBA.TableName"
                //List<FXRate> FxRates = null; // assign list of FXRates;
                //Do not hardcode the connection string here
                //Do not create the redundant connection Object for SqlConnection, use the conncetionObject given in the method parameter.
                List<FXRate> FxRates = new List<FXRate>();
                List<Trade> trades = new List<Trade>();

                try
                {
                    SqlConnection conne = sqlConnectionObject;            
                        string queryString = "Select * from SBA.Trade_Details";
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conne);
                        conne.Open();


                        SqlDataReader datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                            while (datareader.Read())
                            {
                                Trade validfx = new Trade{TradeId = datareader["TradeId"].ToString(),ISIN = datareader["ISIN"].ToString(),TradeDate = datareader["TradeDate"].ToString(),
                                                            MaturityDate = datareader["MaturityDate"].ToString(),SchemeName = datareader["SchemeName"].ToString(),TradeType = datareader["TradeType"].ToString(),
                                                          Currency = datareader["Currency"].ToString(), Amount = datareader["Amount"].ToString()};
                                trades.Add(validfx);
                            }

                        conne.Close();

                        foreach (Trade trad_para_to_calc_fx in trades)
                        {
                            FXRate fx = new FXRate();
                            fx.TradeId = trad_para_to_calc_fx.TradeId;
                            fx.Currency = trad_para_to_calc_fx.Currency;
                            fx.Amount = trad_para_to_calc_fx.Amount;
                            float amount = float.Parse(fx.Amount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                            if (trad_para_to_calc_fx.Currency == "USD")
                            {
                                fx.AppliedFXRate = float.Parse("0.5",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat).ToString();
                                float app_fx_rate = float.Parse("0.5",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                                fx.CalculatedFXRate = ((app_fx_rate) * (amount)).ToString();
                            }
                            if (trad_para_to_calc_fx.Currency == "GBP")
                            {
                                fx.AppliedFXRate = float.Parse("0.6", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat).ToString();
                                float app_fx_rate = float.Parse("0.7",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                                fx.CalculatedFXRate = ((app_fx_rate) * (amount)).ToString();
                            }
                            if (trad_para_to_calc_fx.Currency == "EUR")
                            {
                                fx.AppliedFXRate = float.Parse("0.7", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat).ToString();
                                float app_fx_rate = float.Parse("0.7",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                                fx.CalculatedFXRate = ((app_fx_rate) * (amount)).ToString();
                            }
                            if (trad_para_to_calc_fx.Currency == "INR")
                            {
                                fx.AppliedFXRate = float.Parse("1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat).ToString();
                                float app_fx_rate = float.Parse("1",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                                fx.CalculatedFXRate = ((app_fx_rate) * (amount)).ToString();
                            }
                            FxRates.Add(fx);   
                        }

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new FXCalculatorException(ex.Message);
                }




                return FxRates;
            }

            public bool SaveFXRate(List<FXRate> fxRates, SqlConnection sqlConnectionObject)
            {
                //Do your logic here to upload to DB table
                //Do not hardcode the connection string here
                //Do not create the redundant connection Object for SqlConnection, use the conncetionObject given in the method parameter.
                //Do not Prefix Database name in the SQL Query. Query should be "Insert into SBA.TableName"
                //Should not be "Insert into DatabaseName.SBA.TableName"
                try
                {
                    if (fxRates.Count > 0 && fxRates != null)
                    {
                        SqlConnection conne = sqlConnectionObject;
                        conne.Open();
                        foreach(FXRate calculated in fxRates)
                        {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into SBA.FX_Rate (TradeId,Currency,Amount,AppliedFXRate,CalculatedFXRate) values (@TradeId,@Currency,@Amount,@AppliedFXRate,@CalculatedFXRate)", conne);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TradeId", calculated.TradeId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Currency",calculated.Currency);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount",calculated.Amount);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppliedFXRate",calculated.AppliedFXRate);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CalculatedFXRate", calculated.CalculatedFXRate);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        conne.Close();
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new FXCalculatorException(ex.Message);
                }

                return true;
            }

            public bool CopyToArchive(string sourcePathWithFileName, string targetPathWithFileName)
            {
                //Do your logic here
                //Do not hardcode the filename and the file path here
                try
                {
                    string inputpath="";
                    string input="";
                    FileInfo[] files;
                    DirectoryInfo Di;
                string targetFile = sourcePathWithFileName + targetPathWithFileName;
                Di = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\frameworksample\");
                files = Di.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                foreach (FileInfo di1 in files)
                {

                    if (di1.Name == "TradeOrders_032013.txt")
                    {
                         inputpath = di1.DirectoryName.ToString();
                         input = inputpath+"\\" + di1.Name.ToString();
                    }
                }

                    if (!Directory.Exists(sourcePathWithFileName))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(sourcePathWithFileName);
                        var targetfilecreation = File.Create(targetFile);
                        targetfilecreation.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        File.Delete(targetFile);
                        Directory.Delete(sourcePathWithFileName, true);
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(sourcePathWithFileName);
                        var targetfilecreation =File.Create(targetFile);
                        targetfilecreation.Close();
                     }

                    System.IO.File.Copy(input, targetFile, true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new FXCalculatorException(ex.Message);
                }

                //File.Copy(sourcePathWithFileName + "\\" + targetPathWithFileName, true);
                return true;

            }

            private void ProcessData(Main main)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            //internal void ProcessData(string p, string p_2, string p_3, string p_4, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connectionObject, string p_5, string p_6)
            //{
            //    throw new NotImplementedException();
            //}
        }
    }
```